# How do i remove the label decorator from a submit button

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

In my form i have this code;

```
// Add the submit button
$element = $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
    'ignore'   => true,
    'label' => 'Add new material'
));
$element->removeDecorator('label');
```

However the form still renders with the label element between the  tags.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me:

```
$this->addElements(array(  
  new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit', array(  
    'label' => 'Save'  
  ))  
));  
$element = $this->getElement('submit');  
$element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
```

I did `print_r($element);` to find out what decorators exist for `$element`.

Answer (score 11):

The function addElement returns a reference to the current form not to the last added element.

You could try this:

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
    'ignore'   => true,
    'label'     => 'Add new material'
));

$element = $form->getElement('submit');
$element->removeDecorator('label');
```

Comment: Also

Zend_Db_Element has no function addElement
Zend_Db_Form has

Answer (score 3):

I think the argument to `removeDecorator` is case-sensitive.  I.e., it should be `"Label"` # note the uppercase `'L'`.

Comment: I tried that it doesn't make any difference.

I found this in another answer, but it doesn't seem right to do it this way as it is not how the documentation descibes how to do it.

$element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper')->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd')); 

However, even removing the <dt> element from the html did not solve my overall issue of not being able to position the submit button hard to the left.

Comment: So, you changed this:  $element->removeDecorator('label'); to this:  $element->removeDecorator('Label'); and it still didn't work?  If that's the case perhaps try var_dump(getDecorators()) and let's go from there.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this nuisance I'm defining manually the decorators for my element...

```
$details->addElement('text', 'in_year', array(
    'decorators'=>array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'span')),
    )
));
```

You can of course define your own tags. In this example I only initialise the "ViewHelper" decorator. If I want to initialise the "Label" decorator I would do:

```
$details->addElement('text', 'in_year', array(
    'decorators'=>array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Label',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'span')),
    ),
    'attribs' => array('class' => 'required validate-digits')
));
```

I hope this makes sense... :o)